# Injecting HTML node from an XML document into an HTML document via Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, xml, ajax

After issuing and a Ajax request where I receive XML as a response, there is XML that is already preformatted like HTML. I'd just like to grab that one node from within the XML and inject it into the DOM. There are other pure XML nodes in the response as well. More or less the XML could look like.

```
    <xml>
      <div id="foo">
          <div id='foo'>...
              <img src="foo.jpg"/>
          </div>
      </div>
      <node></node>
      <node></node>
      <node></node>
      <node></node>
    </xml>
```

So if I want to grab the div node, and inject it into the DOM, I can do that with something like

```
    var e = this.responseXML.getElementById('foo');
    $('#container').html(e);
```

The issue is that when the html is injected, the images don't download in anyway. If I use responeTEXT, the images will download, but I get all the other XML that I don't want.

Does anyone know the main reason that the images aren't downloaded when injected? Or how to get them to do that?

Comment: Try `$('#container').empty().append(e);`

Comment: That is essentially the same thing isn't it? Just another way put actually appending the HTML. Doesn't change why the HTML isn't being evaluated and images being requested.

Comment: [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) takes an html string not a node. If the above doesn't work try `$('#container').empty().append($(e).clone());`

Comment: Seemed to still do the same thing :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured out the best way to deal with this. I was not able to get responseXML to ever function the way I wanted with jQuery. I was able to with XUIjs, but it treats objects differently and required a different wrapping of selectors and pulling items from the object arrays. The best solution I found is to use responseText, which seems to be treated as HTML.

```
   var e = this.responseText;
   $('#container').html(e.find("#items"));
```

This loads things fine and causes images to get requested as expected.